# Repetição for para chamar variáveis

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis, for

Tenho quatro variáveis [t1, t2, t3, t4], e cada uma delas foi definida como um string anteriormente.

```
t1 = 'A vida vai ficando cada vez mais dura perto do topo.'
t2 = 'A moralidade é a melhor de todas as regras para orientar a humanidade.'
t3 = 'Aquilo que se faz por amor está sempre além do bem e do mal.'
t4 = 'Torna-te aquilo que és.'
```

Se depois no código, eu quiser chamar cada uma dessas variáveis de uma só vez, pensei em fazer desta forma:

```
for i in range(1,5):
   print(ti)
```

Assim, o i seria substituido pelos números 1 a 4 e então chamaria t1, t2, t3, t4 subsequentemente. Obviamente, esse método não funciona. De fato é possível criar uma lista com os textos e então fazer:

```
lista = [t1, t2, t3, t4]
for i in range(1,5):
   print(lista[i])
```

Porém torna-se antiprático criar uma lista quando o número de variáveis é muito elevado. Minha pergunta é: existe algum modo de chamar múltiplas variáveis previamente definidas de uma vez, como funcionaria na repetição 'for' idealizada acima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Python, em geral, quando se quer usar os _nomes_das_variáveis como variáveis em si, a recomendação é que se use um dicionário.

Ou seja, em vez de ter "f1, f2, f3, f4", você poderia ter um dicionário `f` com as chaves `1, 2, 3 ,4`.

Mas claro que há outras formas - no caso você quer apenas evitar ter que repetir 4 vezes a mesma linha de código. O que você não está levando em conta é que o `for` do Python sempre percorre sequências, e existem várias formas de sequências - não apenas a sequência numérica retornada por `range`.

No caso, tudo o que você precisa é:

```
for var in (f1, f2, f3, f4):
    print(var)
```

Pronto: você cria uma sequência do tipo tupla local com as variáveis desejadas, e cada elmento da tupla é associado à variável do `for` - e você evita ter que repetir o `print` 4 vezes.

**NÂO FAÇA ASSIM** Mas vou incluir para fins de referência:  embora você não deva fazer isso: as próprias variáveis do Python são armazenadas internamente em estruturas do tipo dicionário. Então é possível acessar variáveis programaticamente pelo nome acessando-se esses dicionários que são retornados pela chamada as funções internas `globals()` e `locals()`, respectivamente para variáveis globais e locais.

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(globals()[f"f{i}"])
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porém reescrevi minha pergunta para expressar melhor o que desejava.

Comment: para muitas variáveis: use um dicionário, como explicado na resposta. Variáveis devem ser poucas e com um significado dentro do contexto- se suas variáveis tem um nome que deve ser acessado como dado, como é o que voce quer fazer, um dicionário é o que você precisa.
Note que apesar de eu ter reiterado isso várias vezes, se você quiser mesmo insistir em manter as variáveis com um nome "hardcoded", não quer criar uma lista com as mesmas, e quer iterar sobre as mesmas, pode usar o dicionário de `globals` ou de `locals` como indicado  na última sessão da resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção é usar 'dict comprehensions'.
Altere o valor do range e aumente o número de variáveis:

```
d = {'f' + str(i): 0 for i in range(5)}
```

Produz a seguinte saída:

```
{'f0': 0, 'f1': 0, 'f2': 0, 'f3': 0, 'f4': 0}
```

E para visualizar:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Produz:

```
f0 0
f1 0
f2 0
f3 0
f4 0
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porém reescrevi minha pergunta para expressar melhor o que desejava.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi completamente, mas segue aqui uma possível resposta para esse seu problema:
Se você tiver uma lista, como por exemplo:

```
lista = [f1,f2,f3,f4]
```

Tu pode utilizar a lista diretamente no for:

```
for i in lista:
    print(i)
```

a saída será:

```
f1
f2
f3
f4
```

se quiser o mesmo resultado, mas com o contador, faça:

```
for cont, i in enumerate(lista):
    print(cont)
    print(i)
```

o resultado será:

```
0
1
2
3
f1
f2
f3
f4
```

Assim, podemos resolver o seu problema utilizando um desses métodos, citados acima.
Se quiser criar um vetor com números, faça:

```
lista2 = [] #lista vazia
for i in range(5):
    lista2.append(i)
    print(lista2)
```

O resultado será:

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

Espero ter ajudado, caso não tenha sido respondida, por favor reescreva a sua pergunta. vlw!

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza se entendi sua dúvida, mas pelo que eu entendi você poderia usar um dicionário desta forma:

```
d = {'f1':1,'f2':2,'f3':3,'f4':4}
for x in range(1,5):
    print('{0} => {1}'.format('f'+str(x), d['f'+str(x)]))
```

e imprimir de acordo com sua vontade.
Quando fosse adicionar novos valores você poderia fazer:

```
d['f'+str(int(max(d.keys())[1])+1)] = input()
```

Answer (score -2):

Talvez isso te ajude:

**Lista com 10 objetos**

```py
lista = ['um', 'dois', 'três', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'sete', 'oito',
'nove', 'dez']
```

**Criando 10 variáveis e desempacotando a lista**

```py
for c in range(1, 11):
    globals()[f'numero{str(c)}'] = lista[c - 1]
```

**Imprimindo cada uma das variáveis criadas anteriormente**

```py
for c in range(1, 11):
    print(globals()[f'numero{c}'])
```